# disable GC in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, garbage-collection

I met a strange problem in AS3 and thought the problem may be caused by the GC, can I disable GC explicitly in AS3?

Thanks.
Bin

Comment: Maybe you will find something helpfull in [this](http://jpauclair.net/2010/02/10/mmcfg-treasure/) article.

Comment: I am 99% sure the problem is a bug in your code, and not a bug in the garbage collection. Trying to disable garbage collection is a terrible idea, it's not possible, but if it were, Flash would use up a ton of memory.

Comment: Here is a way to disable as3 gc for specific objects: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15198931/how-to-disable-garbage-collector-as3/15200119#15200119)

Answer (score 1):

i dont think that there is a reference to garbage collection in the program, however you can use the "bugs" in the system to prevent things being cleaned up. if you make a variable that references the object you want to keep safe for example.

why do you think that GC is your problem? it should only take effect when all alues are null, nothing references the object or if it isnt used actively in your code for quite a while. usually the problem is with the lack of gc.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot disable GC.

You have not told us why you think GC is your problem, but that's almost certainly not the case.