# how to disable garbage collector as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

so, I am making really enormous project with as3, and I`d like to know how to disable garbage collector, as user might be on for long and I dont want him or her to just be cut off because garbage collector removed some listener somewhere that should be now needed.

is there easier way to disable garbage collector than go to every single listener and add "false, 0, true" extension after naming the listener?

Comment: This sounds suspect to me, the GC is your friend, I could never imagine the need to avoid the help the GC offers, I mean following best practices you shouldn't even need to worry about it. Also the GC won't remove some listener that you have a reference to, it doesn't work like that

Comment: so, if I have a listener that is tied to some function, like triggering the function in way or other, it is not thrown at gc? I know gc is made in good purpose, but the pretty much the noobie I am facing my first enormous project, I am a bit afraid of it causing break in the flow which will mean problems, like user getting stuck....

Comment: I never even use weak referenced listeners, you add and remove listeners as you see fit, that way you have full control of them. Its the same with objects, you decide what has a ref to them and when to null them to free GC. Just have a destroy method in classes so you can de-ref listeners, stop timers and null objects etc.

Comment: weak referenced? and well yes I add and remove things as I see fit, so the flow keeps up and doesn´t stop or twist oddly because of old listeners (keyboard listeners for example) or objects.

Comment: Yes, weak referenced. The "false, 0, true" thing you talk about means that the listener added to that object will have a weak reference to that object, so when nothing else than that listener is referencing your object it will get destroyed by the GC. Use normal `addEventListener` and remove listeners when you no longer need them.

Comment: Okay, thats what Ive done so far, so I guess I have been worrying about gc for nothing :) I guess I will just continue with the project as I have been and not think about gc. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

No it's not possible, but what you're afraid of isn't really an issue.

Also, making event listeners weak doesn't disable the garbage collector, in fact it makes whatever object they are set to eligible for garbage collection if that is the only reference left to them.

Comment: +1, Also without GC you can get "Out of memory" with no time.

Answer (score 3):

That is possible actually, but it needs discipline...

When an as3 object looses all its references to others, it becomes a candidate for garbage collection. To avoid this you can use the following method:

When you need an object to persist in memory, bind it to somewhere accessible.

Here I supplied an example code.

First create the class below:

```
package your.package.path;

public class noGc {

protected static var vault:Array = [];

// In case we forget that noGc should stay static....   
public function noGc(){throw new Exception('Error: Instance from STATIC noGc');}

public static function hold(o: *): void {
   if(vault.indexOf(o)==-1)vault.push(o); // no multiple references in vault 
}

public static function release(o: *): Boolean {
var i: int = vault.indexOf(o);
    if(i == -1)return(false);            // return value is for information only
    vault.splice(i,1);                   // remove object from vault
    return(true);
}

public static function releaseAll(): void {
    vault.length = 0;
}

} // end class noGc
```

To avoid gc on "yourObject"

```
noGc.hold(yourObject);
```

To allow gc on "yourObject" back

```
noGc.release(yourObject);
```

For normal code flow start holding the objects right after creation of them.
Then you **should** release them at the end of their use.

Also you have to keep an eye on **exceptions** since exceptions break the normal flow you **should** handle them and release the objects becoming **irrelevant** after the exception.

Forgetting an object held means use of unnecessary memory, a.k.a. a **memory leak**.

As I told before, It needs discipline.

Finally, when you need to wipe all objects that are held use,

```
noGc.releaseAll();
```

Hope this helps.